# How can I find what type of Server is running in the background of Windows (seen in services.)

Tags: server, sensors

We have a sensor connected to Computer#1. The sensor is driven by Software XY. This software has a Data Server XY running in the background in Windows. I can see this server by executing "services" after pressing the windows key.

I want to be able to access this Data Server (first in Computer #1, and eventually send/access this information to/from Computer#2).

- **How can I know what type of server is this?** (I need to know this to find out how to connect to it, right?) In the Services application I can only see:
- Service name = XYDataServer
- Display Name = XY Data Server
- Description = Distributes XY data to listening clients
- Path to executable = C:\Program Files\XY\DataServer\XYDataServer.exe
- Additional information which does not say much really

Additional information: the seller of the sensor and software gave us a .NET Assembly  (a .dll) and a word file with some information of the .dll (Namespace, Constructors, Methods, etc.) but no other instructions. I am at a loss on how to proceed. My rational was to first find out what kind of server this is (SQL, Windoes), and then decide how to approach it (pick programming language, download examples, etc.)

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this question without knowing what is the software, what "Data SErver" and etc. Try to be more specific, give to us names, what programming language are you using, what is the type of data you are trying to get.

Comment: @IagoHenrique that is the problem, I have no information on this server besides what I wrote above. I could give the real name of XY corporation, but it would change nothing, the company itself is very obscure and nothing can be found online about it or its software.

Comment: A windows service can be just about anything. There aren't common interfaces to them. If you feel that the doc and dll are inadequate, talk more to the people who gave you those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some tips and technics for information gathering about your target server but they are not precise.
To identify which OS is running on the server you can find a clue by `ping` command. Firstly, you should find IP address of the target server(if you don't have it, you can sniff send/receive package with third party applications like Wireshark). Than ping your target server IP address. Finally, look for TTL in your ping result like this.

```
TTL=64 = *nix - the hop count so if your getting 61 then there are 3 hops and its a *nix device. Most likely Linux.
TTL=128 = Windows - again if the TTL is 127 then the hop is 1 and its a Windows box.
TTL=254 = Solaris/AIX - again if the TTL is 250 then the hop count is 4 and its a Solaris box.
```

For identifying which database is active on the server , you can scan open ports on the server. In example, SQL Server default port is 1433.